# Order of unmounting folders

Tags: linux, mount

Suppose a device is mounted on `/mnt`

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

The folder `/mnt` can then be mounted via `--bind` on another folder, e.g.:

```
mount --bind /mnt /home/user/mountpoint
```

Is the order when unmounting the device from those folders important? Are there any caveats if I first unmount `/mnt` and then the `--bind` mounted folder `/home/user/mountpoint`?

Answer (score 0):

If you run plain `mount` you will see (among others) something like this:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt type whatever (rw,…)
/dev/sdb1 on /home/user/mountpoint type whatever (rw,…)
```

And even if your second command used existing directory `/mnt/foo/bar` instead of `/mnt` the above result would be the same. Notice `/dev/sdb1` in both lines. Conclusion: it's a filesystem (or a part of it) that is mounted, not a path like `/mnt/foo/bar`.

My tests (on Kubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and on Debian 8) indicate one can `umount` these in any order. It looks to me `/mnt` (or `/mnt/foo/bar`) in the second command is used only to determine which part of which filesystem you want to mount again. After that the second mountpoint is somewhat standalone.

However if you do

```
mount --bind /mnt/foo/bar /home/user/mountpoint
rmdir /mnt/foo/bar
```

then you won't be able to create files nor directories under `/home/user/mountpoint`. Run `ls -a /home/user/mountpoint` and you will get nothing (not even `.`).